# Fill empty rows of set with non empty value

Tags: amazon-redshift

Note: I've already gone over related questions like following that don't address my query

- [SQL: how to pick one row for each set of rows with duplicate value in one column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53494179/sql-how-to-pick-one-row-for-each-set-of-rows-with-duplicate-value-in-one-column)
- [Fill missing values with first non-null following value in Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520452/fill-missing-values-with-first-non-null-following-value-in-redshift)

---

I have a sparse, unclean dataset like this

```
| id  | operation | title    | channel_type | mode |
|-----|-----------|----------|--------------|------|
| abc | Start     |          |              |      |
| abc | Start     | recovery |              | Link |
| abc | Start     | recovery | SMS          |      |
| abc | Set       |          | Email        |      |
| abc | Verify    |          | Email        |      |
| pqr | Start     |          |              | OTP  |
| pqr | Verfiy    | sign_in  | Push         |      |
| pqr | Verify    |          |              |      |
| xyz | Start     | sign_up  |              | Link |
```

and I need to fill up empty rows of each `id` with non-empty data available from other rows

```
| id  | operation | title    | channel_type | mode |
|-----|-----------|----------|--------------|------|
| abc | Start     | recovery | SMS          | Link |
| abc | Start     | recovery | SMS          | Link |
| abc | Start     | recovery | SMS          | Link |
| abc | Set       | recovery | Email        | Link |
| abc | Verify    | recovery | Email        | Link |
| pqr | Start     | sign_in  | Push         | OTP  |
| pqr | Verfiy    | sign_in  | Push         | OTP  |
| pqr | Verify    | sign_in  | Push         | OTP  |
| xyz | Start     | sign_up  |              | Link |
```

notes

- some `id`s can have a certain field as empty in all rows
- and while most ids will have same non-empty values for each field, edge cases could have different values. For such groups, filling up any non-empty value in all rows is acceptable. [this is too rare in my dataset and can be ignored]
- another extra bit of pattern is that certain fields are *mostly* only present only against rows of certain `operation`s, for e.g. `mode` is only present against `operation='Start'` rows

---

I've tried grouping rows by `id` while performing `listagg` over `title`, `channel_type` and `mode` columns, followed by `coalesce`, something along the lines of this:

```
WITH my_data AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    operation,
    title,
    channel_type,
    mode
  FROM
    my_db.my_table
),

list_aggregated_data AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    listagg(title) AS titles,
    listagg(channel_type) AS channel_types,
    listagg(mode) AS modes
  FROM
    my_data
  GROUP BY
    id
),

coalesced_data AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    id,
    coalesce(titles) AS title,
    coalesce(channel_types) AS channel_type,
    coalesce(modes) AS mode
  FROM
    list_aggregated_data
),

joined_data AS (
  SELECT
    md.id,
    md.operation,
    cd.title,
    cd.channel_type,
    cd.mode
  FROM
    my_data AS md
  LEFT JOIN
    coalesced_data AS cd ON cd.id = md.id
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
  joined_data
ORDER BY
  id,
  operation
```

But for some reason this is resulting in concatenation of values (presumably from `coalesce` operation), where I get

```
| id  | operation | title            | channel_type | mode |
|-----|-----------|------------------|--------------|------|
| abc | Start     | recoveryrecovery | SMS          | Link |
| abc | Start     | recoveryrecovery | SMS          | Link |
| abc | Start     | recoveryrecovery | SMS          | Link |
| abc | Set       | recoveryrecovery | Email        | Link |
| abc | Verify    | recoveryrecovery | Email        | Link |
| pqr | Start     | sign_in          | Push         | OTP  |
| pqr | Verfiy    | sign_in          | Push         | OTP  |
| pqr | Verify    | sign_in          | Push         | OTP  |
| xyz | Start     | sign_up          |              | Link |
```

---

What's the correct way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with the first_value() window function with the ignore nulls option. You will partition by the first 2 columns and will need to work out the edge cases with some data massaging, likely in the order by clause of the window function.